# "Help to fix 'blur rendering' in flutter web"

Tags: web, flutter, rendering, render

My flutter web is blur at some resolution. Anyone know how to fix it?

For more information, I'm running in debug mode, and when I zoom in or out the page the quality change, some zoom level blur, some not.

[image]

```
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.7.8+hotfix.4, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17763.615], locale en-US)
• Flutter version 1.7.8+hotfix.4 at D:\flutter
• Framework revision 20e59316b8 (3 weeks ago), 2019-07-18 20:04:33 -0700
• Engine revision fee001c93f
• Dart version 2.4.0
```

Comment: Related issue on github: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/32274

Comment: Try to put this style in you index.html, it solved my problem with chrome when downgrading images.

Comment: try this: flutter build web --web-renderer canvaskit

Answer (score 1):

I encountered a [similar issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/89919) when using html renderer for web builds. Flutter web should use CanvasKit by default that should prevent this issue. Otherwise you'd need to define `--web-renderer canvaskit` argument on build.

Answer (score 0):

try to add this line in a `TextStyle` property:

```
 TextStyle(fontFeatures: [FontFeature.proportionalFigures()])
```